# Why does a java.lang.Thread not call the run() method of its explicit java.lang.Runnable when started?

Tags: java, multithreading, polymorphism, overriding

The [Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) state that if we supplied a Runnable *target* when creating a new thread, `.start()` of that thread would run the `run()` method of the supplied runnable.

If that's the case, shouldn't this test code prints "a" (instead of printing "b") ?

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("a");
            }
        };
        Thread t = new Thread(r) {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("b");
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because you are overriding [Thread.run()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#run%28%29) method.

Here is the implementation of [Thread.run()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#run%28%29):

```
@Override
public void run() {
    if (target != null) {
        target.run();
    }
}
```

try:

```
}) {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run(); // ADD THIS LINE
        System.out.println("b");
    }
}.start();
```

You will get `ab`.

Comment: Isn't this a phrasing error with the documentation then? Because the Java docs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread%28java.lang.Runnable%29 state that if we supplied a Runnable target when creating a new thread, .start() of that thread would run the run() method of the supplied runnable (regardless of whether or not we have overridden the Thread's run() method). Which is what I did, but the behavior is not as they have "defined".

Comment: Well strictly speaking the doc is clear, as that's what Thread.run() method provide and not any possible overridden functionality.

Comment: It's like any other methods. You can override and break the contract if the method is not declared final.

Comment: Well, when they say that `start()` of that thread will call the `run()` method of the supplied runnable they are not obligated to strictly mean that `start()` will do that and only that. `start()` may do anything it likes, as long as the `run()` method of the supplied runnable ends up getting called. And apparently the way they implement it (which makes sense, btw) is by making sure that the `run()` method of the thread will be invoked, which in turn invokes the `run()` method of the runnable.

Comment: This is the exact phrasing: "target - the object whose run method is invoked when this thread is started." It's misleading, they should have said something like this: "target - the object whose run method is invoked when this thread is started. (unless Thread.run is overridden)"

Comment: You are right. Consider though that the "unless" part apply to every methods in Java that is not final.

Comment: @Pacerier Technically, you are not calling Thread.start(), you are calling _Thread$1_.start()  (or however Java names the anonymous classes).  So the docs are correct.  Now, perhaps one could argue that Thread.run() should be final.

Comment: @user949300 Bad Api design. It should have obviously been final.

Answer (score 9):

The default implementation is to call the Runnable.  However you are overriding the default implementation and NOT calling the runnable.  The simplest way to fix this is

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("a");
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run(); // call the default implementation.
            System.out.println("b");
        }
    }.start();
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread%28java.lang.Runnable%29 states "target - the object whose run method is invoked when this thread is started." so don't you think that the documentation is sloppily phrased?

Comment: The documentation is correct.  You have overridden the class with a sub-class which behave differently.  You haven't changed the way `Thread` behaves.

Comment: @Pacerier - that's like breaking a drinking glass and then complaining to the manufacturer that it doesn't hold water anymore.

Comment: @Perception Its more like creating a new drinking glass with a hole in the bottom and then complaining the manufacturer of the glass you based it on that your glass doesn't hold water. ;)

Answer (score 3):

The default implementation of Thread.run() does what the javadocs say (look at the source code)

```
public void run() {
    if (target != null) {
        target.run();
    }
}
```

However, Thread.run() is public, and you overrode it, so it calls your println("b"), and totally ignores the Runnable passed in the constructor.  Arguably, Thread.run() should be final, but it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually extending the `Thread` class and calling `start` on the instance of that  anonymous subclass.

I think the confusion is that the "Java Doc" is for the `java.lang.Thread` class not for your class that extends that class.

e.g.

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("a");
    }
};
Thread t = new Thread(r);
```

Now, if it does not call that `run` then java doc is wrong. Which is not true.

Answer (score 1):

You have overridden the default implementation of `Thread.run()` in what I guess is an anonymous subclass, hence what the JavaDoc says no longer applies.

If you try

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("a");
        }
    }) .start();
}
}
```

You get the answer you expect, `a`.

Comment: But shouldn't what the JavaDoc says applies regardless of whether or not I have overridden anything if at all ? (since the documentation didn't state clearly that "the default implementation is this and this which if you override will etc etc"

Comment: It's implied, that's what overriding a method does, it replaces the overridden method with your new implementation. Done correctly it is a powerful way of allowing classes to add new behaviour, such as when you extend the Thread class (which is an alternative to using `Runnable`s). What did you expect to happen and what did you think overriding did?

Answer (score 1):

The first block overrides `run` in `Runnable`.  The second block overrides `run` in `Thread`. When you call `start` on a `Thread`, its `run` method is invoked. The default `run` method in `Thread` calls the `Runnable.run` method but since you overrode `Thread.run` there is no code to start the `Runnable` - only your code to print 'b'.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation that **I** have says this:
"Causes this thread to begin execution; the Java Virtual Machine calls the run method **of this thread.**"
which means that it **should** print `b` instead of `a`, since you have overridden the `run()` method of `Thread`.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling start() method. Reading the docs in the link you provided it states:

> public void start()
>   Causes this thread to begin execution; the Java
>   Virtual Machine calls the run method of this thread.

You should call the run() method if you would like to call the Runnable object's run method.

> public void run() If this thread was constructed using a separate
>   Runnable run object, then that Runnable object's run method is called;
>   otherwise, this method does nothing and returns.